# Providing access to User Groups using Identity Server 3

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api, identityserver3, openid-connect

The application I'm currently working on is a huge ASP.NET MVC web application which uses traditional Windows Authentication model. We are trying to migrate to Single Sign On model using Identity Server 3 and Open ID Connect.

Coming to my question, is there any way/work around to provide access on a user group basis when using Identity Server? The problem here is that the my user groups could either be role based or Active directory groups. I'm looking for something like InMemoryGroup (similar to InMemoryUser).

Something that mimicks the following for a Group of users that can be role based or not:

```
new InMemoryUser
            {
                Username = "harry",
                Password = "thisispassword@123",
                Subject = "1",
                Claims = new Claim[]
                {
                    new Claim(Constants.ClaimTypes.Name, "Harry Potter"),
                    new Claim(Constants.ClaimTypes.GivenName, "Harry"),
                    new Claim(Constants.ClaimTypes.FamilyName, "Potter"),
                    new Claim(Constants.ClaimTypes.Email, "harry.potter@hogwarts.com"),
                    new Claim(Constants.ClaimTypes.EmailVerified, "true", ClaimValueTypes.Boolean),
                    new Claim(Constants.ClaimTypes.Role, "Administrator"),
                }
            }
```

I'm relatively new to Identity Server and Open ID Connect and not able to find anything online and would really appreciate any leads.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To represent the fact that a user is a member of a group you just add a claim. You could add:

```
new Claim("Group", "Hogwarts Student")
```

to your in memory user. The claim indicates that Harry is a member of the "Hogwarts Student" group. There is a couple of things going on here you want to be aware of. The constructor being called is:

```
new Claim(string claimType, string claimValue)
```

There Identity Server provides some standard ones in the Constants class but you can make up your own. Also, you can have multiple group claims, so you could have

```
new Claim("Group", "Hogwarts Student"),
new Claim("Group", "Gryffindor House)
```

If you wanted to see if Harry was in the "Gryffindor House" group, you'd just search through is list of claims where the claim type is equal to "Group" and the claim value is equal to "Gryffindor House".

Finally, the difference between groups and roles is generally more a matter of application semantics that a physical difference in how they are stored. In general, the set of users that can perform the "Administrator" role for an application is just a group of users. It is the way that an application treats users of a group that makes the group a role.

Comment: Works in my use case :) Accepting as answer